# Can I say "I delve into photography" to say I do photography more or less seriously?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have seen the term "delve" in the context of discussions "tonight we delve into the consequences of..." or in its archaic acceptation for "excavate" but I have not really seen it as a way to convey that someone engages in an activity. I'm mostly interested that the person reading it will understand that I do photography; I'm not concerned about they realizing I do it seriously (although, ideally that would be conveyed too, it's just not a priority). I did google this exact phrase and it does show up, but none of the pages I found it in were authoritative, hence here I am asking. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/delve-into-sth). I think _delve_ always has the connotation of searching, not just engaging in an activity.

Comment: @Kate Yes; [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delve#:~:text=1%20%3A%20to%20dig%20or%20labor,delve) also requires that the approach be in depth.

Comment: I've always interpreted "delve", in this sense, to mean about the same as "dive".  Ie, one enters the area of study with vigor, and submerses oneself in the topic.

Comment: I think you could use it like this: *I am delving into photography.*, referring to sustained research of some kind.

Comment: *Delve* represents an action. It doesn’t convey the state of the entity doing the delving, other than a desire to know more at the end of the delving than they did at the beginning.  A cooking class might delve into the minutae of cookie sprinkles. A researcher in biochemistry might delve into the resonant structures of large molecules. Sometimes, state can be inferred from action.  With *delve*, the inference is pretty weak.

Answer (score 3):

"I dabble with photography now and then" : Not Serious
"I am a dilettante in photography" : Not Serious

"I am keenly into photography" : Serious
"I am skilled in photography" : Serious

Delve [ to examine something carefully ] is not suitable, which Kate Bunting has commented earlier.

Comment: _Delving_ is Not Serious, too. Or either.